# Переполнение блока до верхней границы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, style

Создаю мини-версию консоли на JS. Каждая введённая строка создаёт новый div с моим текстом или текстом ответа и добавляет его в общий блок. Но несмотря на добавленный overflow: scroll; бегунки появляются и остаются неактивными даже когда текст лезет за край блока, где благополучно скрывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#terminalbody {
  width: 55vw;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#terminalbody>div {
  color: rgb(96, 194, 16);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста выставить код, как вы добавляете?

Comment: let reply = document.createElement('div');
reply.textContent = prinput;
document.querySelector('#terminalbody').appendChild(reply);

Какие же тут неудобные комментарии, боже...

Comment: Не стоит писать код в комментарии... Просто корректируй текст своего вопроса. Сделай тестовый пример его можно будет тут запустить и посмотреть как работает.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой. Нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M, вставьте там ваш код по нужным секциям, обязательно нажмите кнопку "Привести в порядок", нажмите на "Запустить". Убедитесь, что всё отображается как надо и нет других ошибок, кроме тех, о которых вы спрашиваете

Comment: Вот это свойство влияет -  `justify-content: flex-end;`. Я бы мог сделать предположение, почему значение `flex-end` вызывает такой эффект, но всё равно это будут лишь логические догадки. Поэтому пусть объяснит тот, кто уже сталкивался и разобрался )

Comment: P.S. [Решение на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515194) - убрать свойство `justify-content` и добавить первому элементу: `#terminalbody > div:first-child { margin-top: auto; }`

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Первый раз пользуюсь со если честно, буду знать. Осталось придумать как сделать так, чтобы блок пролистывался к нижней части автоматически, но уже попробую сам. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: на счет автопрокрутки, попробуй каждому блоку давать id и на него переходить. типа `index.html#tag_id`